# Using the glTF C# loader on a Xamarin Android project

Tags: c#, parsing, xamarin, xamarin.android, gltf

I tried to use the NuGet package "glTF loader" for my Xamarin Android C# project, but every time I try to load a model with:

```
Gltf model = Interface.LoadModel(mystream);
```

...my application crashes with a System.NotSupportedException.

Is this loader win32 only? Is there any other way to import 3d models without writing the parser completely from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've recently used SharpGLTF (https://github.com/vpenades/SharpGLTF) in a project to support gltf2 files in an optimization pipeline suite that included a testing app in Android (written in Xamarin.Android and it works fine, for what it currently supports).

i.e. SharpGLTF does support some extensions, unlike glTF loader which is a reference loader and thus does not support any), but not things like Google Draco as that is native C++ (assuming it could be built via NDK) but this app's glTF optimization pipeline was not using Draco models anyway.

```
var model = ModelRoot.Load(Path.Combine(playgroundDir, modelName));
// optimize model...
model.SaveGLB(Path.Combine(CacheDir.CanonicalPath, "model.glb"));
```

Comment: thank you so, so much! I did not enable the search for alpha projects! You saved my life!